# Preventing a DataGridView from selecting the first item

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForm DataGridView that when I populate it with data the first item is selected by default.  I don't want this to occur as to when an item is selected an event fires and some code is executed.  Solutions I have for this is to unhook-bind-rehook the event or have a flag that is changed the first time the event fires after a new databind.  However I was wondering if there is something a little more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem (but I don't use the SelectionChanged event), and this works for me:

In the constructor, after the binding is set, add a handler to the DataBindingComplete event:

```
dgvCommandos.DataSource = systeemCommandos; // = my List<> of objects
dgvCommandos.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(dgvCommandos_DataBindingComplete);
```

The handler:

```
void dgvCommandos_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dgvCommandos.ClearSelection();
}
```

If you intend to select a row (e.g. after adding/inserting a new object), simply set:

```
dgvCommandos.Rows[insertPos].Selected = true;
```

Using this as a basis, I think it is possible to handle other events to react upon user selection. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a winforms app open to test, but I'm curious if you have an intervening BindingSource between your data and the datagridview?  If so, what if you set

```
List<Data> data = GetMyData();
BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource();
myBindingSource.DataSource = data;
myBindingSource.position = -1;
myGrid.DataSource = myBindingSource;
```

I often find it helpful to intervene a BindingSource object between the data and UI.  It seems to help fix a lot of random issues, although I'm more accustomed to using DataTable objects as data rather than List<> objects.

Comment: My Binding Source is a generic List<>

Comment: Right, but you can always intervene a BindingSource object -- give me a sec and I'll update the answer with what I mean

Comment: This doesn't work. Setting `myBindingSource.Position = -1;` and immediately reading it back shows 0, not -1;

Answer (score 2):

What about (sorry, VB.NET but I'm sure you could convert):

```
myGrid.ClearSelection()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the following example:

```
        dataGridView.Columns[0].Selected = false;
        dataGridView.Rows[0].Selected = false;
        dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = false;
```

Of course, check if there are rows, columns, and so on. It's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late, but the only I way i got it working for me (a lot of TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, etc. bound to my DataGridView via BindingSource):

After initializing DataBindings to my Controls and loading the data into DataGridView I had to suspend the binding

```
bindingSource.SuspendBinding();
```

In my RowHeaderMouseClick event I checked if the binding is suspended. If so, just resume it:

```
if(bindingSource.IsBindingSuspended)
    bindingSource.ResumeBinding();
```

This way I can complete the loading and binding of the data (in my case a sortable BindingList), show the data to the user but with no record selected.

Hope this helps at least anybody!